# how to get database back while xampp is not working

Tags: database, phpmyadmin, xampp, localhost

I have created a database in MySQL using XAMPP But In Some How My XAMPP Server is Not Working Now I am trying to Get My data Back

Comment: What is the error message you're seeing? Does the MySQL service even start?

Answer (score 1):

It's in

> xampp\mysql\data

folder. Or you can export the database in PHPmyadmin.

Comment: how can i export database phpmyadmin is not working

Answer (score 0):

If you use Linux, you can install mysql-client and mysql-server:

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-client
sudo apt-get install mysql-server
```

and then access to phpMyAdmin with navigate to where you extract mysql. Then run this command:

```
php -S localhost:80
```

If you use windows, you can use an alternative software instead. I think [Laragon](https://laragon.org/) is a good alternative software.